# url tag in generic views and noreversematch error

Tags: django, django-templates, django-generic-views

Following the cms project from "practical django project" i face an issue with the render functionality. In particular i have a view function called category_detail and i have a link reference in base.html which uses the url tag. this is Categories.

Whenever the server be reloaded returns:

```
>Exception Type:    NoReverseMatch

>Exception Value:   Reverse for 'coltrane_category_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

there is an blank category_list.html in urls dir of coltrane's  dir.

If i handcode the href value it works just fine. What am i losing here?

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import * 
from coltrane.models import Category 

urlpatterns =patterns('', 
    (r'^$','django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list',{'queryset':Category.objec‌ts.all()}), 
    (r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$','coltrane.views.category_detail'), 
)
```

Comment: can you show the url pattern corresponding to : `coltrane_category_list` ?

Comment: from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from coltrane.models import Category

urlpatterns =patterns('',
                      (r'^$','django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list',{'queryset':Category.objects.all()}),
                      (r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$','coltrane.views.category_detail'),
)

Comment: Please edit the question. It is much more readable.

Comment: You dont have a `coltrane_category_list` at all ??

Comment: This implementation is based on the book and it should work, shouldnt it? It uses generic views.